# Prime number $p=4n+1$ is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Prime number $p=4n+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Comment: any prime number $p\in \mathbb Z$ with $p\equiv 3(mod 4)$ is prime in $\mathbb Z[i]$ , for more details in the book *Algebraic number theory, Mollin*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Use the famous theorem of Fermat:

If $p > 2$ is prime then $p = a^2 + b^2$, for some natural numbers $a$ and $b$, if and only if $p = 4n+1$ for some natural number $n$.

Now once you have written  $p = a^2 + b^2$ then you can factorize it in the Gaussian Integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and hence it is not prime!

Comment: I want to prove that $p$ is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and then prove the Fermat's theorem.

Comment: but your questions does not seems to ask so!!

Comment: There are many other ways to prove the fermat's theorem!

Answer (score 1):

See $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is practically $ \frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{X^2 + 1}$. Now  p is prime if $ \frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{(X^2 + 1,p)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}_p[X]}{\overline{X}^2 + 1}$ is an integral domain. where $ \overline{X}$ is the image of X in modulo p . So this is integral domain whether $X^2 + 1$ is reducible in modulo p or not. And by an elementary number theorem ,we get $X^2 \equiv -1$ modulo p has a solution iff $ p = 4n + 1$.